# matrix subs in sympy

Tags: sympy, substitution

I am trying to compute some symbolic expressions with matrices using sympy. The behavior of sympy function subs is strange for matrices. What I need is to take string with symbolic expression, substitute some particular matrices instead symbols in this expression and compute the results.

For scalars the sympy.subs does the job:

```
import sympy as sp
sp.sympify("x1*x2**2").subs({"x1":5,"x2":10})
```

gives 500 as expected.

If instead scalars I use matrices like

```
sp.sympify("x1*x2**2").subs({"x1":sp.Matrix([[0,1],[1,0]]),"x2":sp.Matrix([[1,0],[0,1]])}
```

the result is `AttributeError: 'MatPow' object has no attribute 'as_base_exp'`. This seems strange as long as

```
aa,bb = sp.Matrix([[0,1],[1,0]]), sp.Matrix([[1,0],[0,1]])
aa*bb**2
```

works as expected.

What is the correct way to perform such calculations in sympy?

Answer (score 3):

`sympify` is going to convert `x1` and `x2` into Symbols, but for this to work they need to be MatrixSymbols, like

```
x1 = MatrixSymbol('x1', 2, 2)
x2 = MatrixSymbol('x2', 2, 2)
(x1*x2**2).subs({x1: Matrix([[0,1],[1,0]]), x2: Matrix([[1,0],[0,1]])})
```

This is unevaluated by default but you can evaluate it with `.doit`, like

```
(x1*x2**2).subs({x1: Matrix([[0,1],[1,0]]), x2: Matrix([[1,0],[0,1]])}).doit()
```

Comment: Thank you. So, MatrixSymbols are not Symbols ()? It is hard to get from the sympy documentation. Are these nuances documented somewhere in more details?

Comment: By the way, I found another workaround: `from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr; print parse_expr("x1*x2**2", local_dict={"x1":sp.Matrix([[0,1],[1,0]]),"x2":sp.Matrix([[1,0],[0,1]])})
Matrix([[0, 1], [1, 0]])`. Surprisingly, this works as well

Comment: You can also pass `locals` to `sympify`.

Comment: @Misha MatrixSymbols are special symbols that represent matrices. They differ from normal Symbols in that they carry a shape, and they do the right thing if you combine them with actual matrices or substitute them for actual matrices (as you can see here). They also, for instance, are noncommutative by default (Symbols are only noncommutative if you set `commutative=False` when you create them). See http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/expressions.html.